# React form submission logic with lifted state and controlled dependence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've dug myself into a deep rabbit hole with this component in an attempt to use React hooks.

The Parent component handles a `dictionary` state which is eventually distributed to multiple components.

My problem child component `WordInput` has a form with a single input. When submitting the form the component is fetching the word's definition from an API and passing on both the word and the definition to the parent which then sets the state in the form of `dictionary`. So far, so good IF it's the first word in `dictionary`. The part I'm having trouble with is to submit any subsequent words/definitions.

When the user submits a subsequent word, I want the component to check whether the word already exists in the `dictionary` that is passed to the child. If it doesn't exist, add it to the `dictionary` via the submit function.

I think the problem is that I'm trying to do too much with `useEffect`
I `useEffect` to:
  - set loading
  - check and process the dictionary for existing words
  - check that definition and word aren't empty and submit both to parent/dictionary
  - fetch a definition from an API

In the unprocessed code, I have multiple `console.groups` to help me keep track of what is happening. The more I add to the component, the more Subgroups and subgroups of subgroups accumulate. Clearly, the approach I'm taking isn't very dry and causes too many re-renders of the component/useEffect functions. For conciseness, I have taken out the `console.log` entries.

The imported `fetchWordDefinition` merely processes the fetched data and arranges it correctly into an array.

I don't know how to keep this dry and effective, and any help is appreciated with this rather simple task. My hunch is to keep all the logic to submit the word/definition in the submit handler, and only use `useEffect` to validate the data prior to that.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import fetchWordDefinition from "./lib/utils";

const WordInput = ({ onSubmit, dictionary }) => {
    const [definition, setDefinition] = useState([]);
    const [cause, setCause] = useState({ function: "" });
    const [error, setError] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [word, setWord] = useState("");
    const [wordExistsInDB, setWordExistsInDB] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const dictionaryEmpty = dictionary.length === 0 ? true : false;

        if (dictionaryEmpty) {
            return;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i += 1) {
                if (dictionary[i].word === word) {
                    setWordExistsInDB(true);
                    setError({ bool: true, msg: "Word already exists in DB" });
                    break;
                } else {
                    setWordExistsInDB(false);
                    setError({ bool: false, msg: "" });
                }
            }
        }
    }, [dictionary, word]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const definitionNotEmpty = definition.length !== 0 ? true : false;
        const wordNotEmpty = word !== "" ? true : false;

        if (wordNotEmpty && definitionNotEmpty && !wordExistsInDB) {
            onSubmit(word, definition);
            setWord("");
            setDefinition([]);
        }
    }, [definition, word, onSubmit, wordExistsInDB]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cause.function === "fetch") {
            async function fetchFunction() {
                const fetch = await fetchWordDefinition(word);
                return fetch;
            }

            fetchFunction().then(definitionArray => {
                setDefinition(definitionArray);
                setCause({ function: "" });
            });
        }
    }, [cause, word]);

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setLoading(true);
        setCause({ function: "fetch" });
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {error.bool ? <span>{error.msg}</span> : null}
            <input
                name='word'
                placeholder='Enter Word'
                type='text'
                value={word}
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setWord(value)}
            />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    );
};

export default WordInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed more `useEffect`'s happening than necessary, as well as most of the state. All you need is the `handleSubmit` to do the fetching.

```
const WordInput = ({ onSubmit, dictionary }) => {
  const [word, setWord] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(e => {
    setWord(e.currentTarget.value)
  }, [])
  const handleSubmit = React.useCallback(() => {
    //check if word is in dictionary
    const wordIsAlreadyThere = dictionary.map(entry => entry.word).includes(word)
    //fetch the definition, wait for it, and call submit
    if(!wordIsAlreadyThere && word.length > 0){
      fetchWordDefinition(word)
        .then(definition => {
          onSubmit(word, definition)
          setWord('')
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        value={word}
        onChange={handleChange}/>
      <input type='submit' />
     </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing out on some clarity and what `useEffect` is for

A functional component gets re-ran everytime either a prop or a state changes. `useEffect` runs when the component gets created, and we use it for things like doing a first-time fetch, or subscribing to an event handler. The second argument (array of variables) is used so that, if we have for example a blog post with with comments etc, we don't re-fetch everything unless the ID changes (meaning it's a new blog post)

Looking at your code, we have this flow:

1. User inputs something and hits Submit
2. Check if the word exists in a dictionary

   a. If it exists, display an error message

   b. If it doesn't exist, fetch from an API and call `onSubmit`

So really the only state we have here is the word. You can just compute an error based on if the word is in the dictionary, and the API call is done in a callback (`useCallback`). You have a lot of extra state that doesn't really matter in a state-way

A simplified version would look like this

```
const WordInput = ({ onSubmit, dictionary }) => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  // `find` will find the first entry in array that matches
  const wordExists = !!dictionary.find(entry => entry.word === word)

  // Ternary operator, 
  const error = (wordExists) ? "Word already exists in DB" : null

  // When user hits submit
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    if (wordExists || !word.length) return;

    setLoading(true)
    fetchFunction()
      .then(definitionArray => {
        onSubmit(word, definitionArray)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {error && <span>{error}</span>}

          <input
              name='word'
              placeholder='Enter Word'
              type='text'
              value={word}
              onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setWord(value)}
          />
          <input type='submit' onclick={handleSubmit} disabled={wordExists}/>
      </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'd like to add the following. useEffect not only runs when the component mounts, but also when any of the state variables change. It appears that setLoading is never set back to false in your snippet.

Comment: Oops sorry, just typed it out from memory real fast. You would do `setLoading(false)` in the `.then()` when the API has resolved, before `onSubmit()`. You can also setWord to an empty string too

Answer (score 0):

Your component only needs to keep track of the `word` and the `loading` flag.

- When the user changes the word input it updates the word state.
- When the user submits the form the loading state changes. This triggers a `useEffect` that will first check if the word already exists. If not it proceeds to fetch it and add both the word and its definition to the dictionary.

---

```
const WordInput = ({ onSubmit, dictionary }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [word, setWord] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading) return;

        const existing_word = dictionary.find(item => item.word === word);

        if (existing_word) return;

        const fetchFunction = async () => {
            const definition = await fetchWordDefinition(word);

            // Update the dictionary
            onSubmit(word, definition);

            // Reset the component state
            setWord("");
            setLoading(false);
        };

        fetchFunction();
    }, [loading]);

    return (
        <form
            onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (word.length) {
                    setLoading(true);
                }
            }}
        >
            <input
                name="word"
                placeholder="Enter Word"
                type="text"
                value={word}
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setWord(value)}
            />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
};
```

Please let me know if something is not clear or I missed something.